# SonarQube - how to deactivate inherited rule in quality profile?

Tags: sonarqube

Using SonarQube, we wish to create a new quality profile from an existing profile, but deactivate a couple of the rules. The GUI allows us to modify the severity of inherited rules, but not deactivate the rules.

Is there any way to achieve this?

A workaround is to copy the profile and modify it, but we wish to retain the link to the original profile so that our inherited profile picks up any changes that are made to the original profile.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not possible to deactivate a rule inherited from a parent quality profile.

Comment: Any evolutions/plans since this answer ?

Comment: This is an old question, but with SQ 6.6 it seems it is still impossible to deactivate an inherited rule. Same question as the previous comment: any plans to make this possible ? Thanks

Comment: You should just change how it is called : it's not "inheritance" you are doing, it's "links". Or you can implement real inheritance like in object languages of course.

Comment: This continues to be a problem in 8.1

Comment: That’s not actually true.  You can leverage the SonarProperties file to turn OFF any rule in your project.  Here is a perfect example on GitHub of someone doing just this.
https://github.com/simgrid/simgrid/blob/master/sonar-project.properties

Answer (score 17):

Independent of the used profile, you can always ignore rules on the project level: Go to the project's *Administration --> General Settings* menu. From there, go to *Analysis Scope --> Issues*.

Add the rule(s) you want to ignore to the *Ignore Issues on Multiple Criteria* list with `**` as *File Path Pattern*.

Comment: Does one add the label of a rule (e.g. "String literals should not be duplicated" or the id (e.g. "php:S1192")?

Comment: You have to use the id, i.e. php:S1192

Answer (score 0):

So you just edit your sonar-project.properties file and you can turn off any rule for JUST your project.

Follow this template example here:  https://github.com/simgrid/simgrid/blob/master/sonar-project.properties